# PHP preg_match words in changing order

Tags: php, preg-match

Supposing I have an `array ("things and stuff", "the stuff");` that I am iterating through to compare each element to each element of another array - assume the second array is `("stuff the blah", "stuff and things to do");`

And I want to `preg_match` anything that is generally relevant - I need it to match elements wherein the words are the same, even though their position has been changed - essentially I want `"the stuff"` to match `"stuff the..."` in this case.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with preg_match, I'd suggest rephrasing the question to something like this: I have two arrays of strings and I want to find pairs of strings from both arrays that contain at least one common word.

Comment: Use `explode` to convert the strings into arrays, then `array_intersect` to check whether they contain the same words.

Comment: See my example just like what @Barmar said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply split string of your first array to be compared with all string values on second array, here the example:

```
$array1 = array("things and stuff", "the stuff");
$array2 = array("stuff the blah", "stuff and things to do");

$result = array();

foreach($array1 as $val1){

    $words1 = explode(" ", $val1);

    $result[$val1] = 'not found';

    foreach($array2 as $val2){

        $words2 = explode(" ", $val2);
        $intersect = array_intersect($words1, $words2);
        $diff = array_diff($words1, $intersect);

        if(empty($diff))
            $result[$val1] = 'found';
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

References:

- [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [array_ intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)
- [array_ diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)